# LARAVEL : relation "table" does not exist LINE 1: select * from "table" ^ (SQL: select * from "table")

Tags: apache, postgresql, laravel-5, migration

I have an application in laravel 5.3 running on the Apache server, I vhosts I configured the apache and it worked well, but when I try query my database returns "table" relationship does not exist. If I access localhost with php artisan serve works well. Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `psql` to connect to your database server, make sure you are connected to correct database.

To list available databases run `\l` command, to connect to specific one run `\c database_name`, to list tables in a database run `\dt`.

Comment: thanks, I solved my problem by granting all privileges to the user.